# Am trying to Use button to Load html file from asset folder

Tags: android, android-studio, android-webview

Am trying to Use button to Load html file from asset folder 
but after clicking the button the html file refuse to load

Activity_main.xml

```xml
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/btn1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="open"
    android:text="lawal"
    android:textSize="20dp" />

<WebView
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="495dp"
    android:id="@+id/webView"
/>
```

Main.java

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    WebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void open(View view) {
        webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebView webView = new WebView(this);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView.loadUrl("file:///Android_asset/1.html");
        setContentView(view);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**android_asset** should be in lower case.Change your button onClick() code as below. here **test.html** should be replaced by your file name. 
you need to create assets folder inside main folder.

```
WebView webView = view.findViewById(R.id.webView);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/test.html");
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the webview in oncreate after setting the content view

`setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);`

and then load your url in open function

```
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/1.html");
```